# std::condition_variable – notify once but wait thread wakened twice

Tags: c++, multithreading

Here's a simple C++ thread pool implementation. It's an altered version orginated from https://github.com/progschj/ThreadPool.

```
#ifndef __THREAD_POOL_H__
#define __THREAD_POOL_H__

#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <future>
#include <functional>
#include <stdexcept>

namespace ThreadPool {

class FixedThreadPool {
 public:
  FixedThreadPool(size_t);

  template<class F, class... Args>
  auto Submit(F&& f, Args&&... args)
      -> std::future<typename std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type>;

  template<class F, class... Args>
  void Execute(F&& f, Args&&... args);

  ~FixedThreadPool();

  void AwaitTermination();

  void Stop();

 private:
  void ThreadWorker();

  // need to keep track of threads so we can join them
  std::vector<std::thread> workers;

  // the task queue
  std::queue< std::function<void()> > tasks;

  // synchronization
  std::mutex worker_mutex;
  std::mutex queue_mutex;
  std::condition_variable condition;

  // stop flag
  bool stop_;

  // thread size
  int thread_size_;
};

// Constructor does nothing. Threads are created when new task submitted.
FixedThreadPool::FixedThreadPool(size_t num_threads): 
    stop_(false),
    thread_size_(num_threads) {}

// Destructor joins all threads
FixedThreadPool::~FixedThreadPool() {
  //std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
  for(std::thread &worker: workers) {
    if (worker.joinable()) {
      worker.join();
    }
  }
}

// Thread worker
void FixedThreadPool::ThreadWorker() {
  std::function<void()> task;
  while (1) {
    {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->queue_mutex);
      this->condition.wait(lock,
                     [this]() { return this->stop_ || !this->tasks.empty(); });
      printf("wakeeeeeened\n");
      if (this->stop_ && this->tasks.empty()) {
        printf("returning ...\n");
        return;
      }
      task = std::move(this->tasks.front());
      this->tasks.pop();
    }
    task();
  }
}

// Add new work item to the pool
template<class F, class... Args>
auto FixedThreadPool::Submit(F&& f, Args&&... args)
    -> std::future<typename std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type >
{
  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->worker_mutex);
    if (workers.size() < thread_size_) {
      workers.emplace_back(std::thread(&FixedThreadPool::ThreadWorker, this));
    }
  }

  using return_type = typename std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type;

  auto task = std::make_shared< std::packaged_task<return_type()> >(
      std::bind(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...)
  );

  std::future<return_type> res = task->get_future();
  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(queue_mutex);
    if(stop_) {
      throw std::runtime_error("ThreadPool has been shutdown.");
    }
    tasks.emplace([task]() { (*task)(); });
  }
  condition.notify_one();
  return res;
}

// Execute new task without returning std::future object.
template<class F, class... Args>
void FixedThreadPool::Execute(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
  Submit(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

// Blocks and wait for all previously submitted tasks to be completed.
void FixedThreadPool::AwaitTermination() {
  for(std::thread &worker: workers) {
    if (worker.joinable()) {
      worker.join();
    }
  }
}

// Shut down the threadpool. This method does not wait for previously submitted
// tasks to be completed.
void FixedThreadPool::Stop() {
  printf("Stopping ...\n");
  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(queue_mutex);
    stop_ = true;
  }
}


} // namespace ThreadPool

#endif /* __THREAD_POOL_H__ */
```

and the test main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <exception>

#include "ThreadPool.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  ThreadPool::FixedThreadPool pool(3);

  pool.Execute([]() {
      std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
    }
  );
  pool.Stop();
  pool.AwaitTermination();
  std::cout << "All tasks complted." << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I have a bug in this test program. Only one task is submitted to threadpool, but I got working thread being wakened up twice:

```
>>./test 
Stopping ...
wakeeeeeened
hello world
wakeeeeeened
returning ...
All tasks complted.
```

I think the problem is in FixedThreadPool::ThreadWorker() itself. The working thread continuously wait on a conditional variable to get new tasks. The function FixedThreadPool::Submit() adds a new task to queue and call condition.nofity_one() to waken a working thread.

But I can't figure out how the working thread can be wakened twice. I have  only one task submitted and exactly one working thread in this test.

Comment: Might have something to do with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup

Comment: @cppguy Not with the predicate version.

Comment: OT: Your include guard is *very* illegal! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier

Comment: First wake is from the `notify_one()`; second one is because the `wait()` call happens to execute after the `Stop()` call, so the predicate returns true, `wait()` returns immediately, and no wait actually takes place. (Should be obvious that you got lucky here; if the wait happened first then you'd have a deadlock, barring spurious wakeup.)

Comment: @T.C. Shouldn't that be an answer, not a comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting comments into answer:

`condition_variable::wait(lock, pred)` is equivalent to `while(!pred()) wait(lock);`. If `pred()` returns `true` then no wait actually takes place and the call returns immediately.

Your first wake is from the `notify_one()` call; the second "wake" is because the second `wait()` call happens to execute after the `Stop()` call, so your predicate returns `true` and `wait()` returns immediately without waiting.

It should be obvious that you got (un)lucky here: if the second `wait()` call took place before the `Stop()` call, then your worker thread will be stuck waiting forever (in the absence of spurious wakeups), and so will your main thread.

Also, get rid of `__THREAD_POOL_H__`. Burn those double underscores to the ground.